# Proving integrability of composite of measurable functions, doubt in procedure

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

I know this question has been asked before. The thing is that im not entirely sure of my procedure. The problem is:

**Problem:**
Let $(\Omega,F,\mu)$ a measure space, $(X,G)$ a measurable space and $f:\Omega \rightarrow X$ measurable function. For $A \in G$, we define $\upsilon(A)=\mu(f^{-1}(A))$.

a) Prove that if $g:X\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ measurable, then $\int_{X}gd\upsilon = \int_{\Omega} g \circ fd\mu.$

b) $g:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Show that g is $\upsilon$-integrable **iff** $g\circ f$ is $\mu$-integrable and in this case show the equality of a).

**SOLUTION**

a) 1. Lets prove it for indicator functions, so let $g=\mathbb{1}_{A}(x)$ for $A\in G$. So $\int_{X}g d\upsilon = \int_{X}\mathbb{1}_{A}(x)d\upsilon=\int_{A}d\upsilon=\upsilon(A)=\mu(f^{-1}(A))=\int_{f^{-1}(A)}d\mu=\int_{\Omega}\mathbb{1}_{f^{-1}(A)}(x)d\mu = \int_{\Omega} \mathbb{1}_{A}(f(x))=\int_{\Omega} g \circ fd\mu$

2. For simple functions it follows from the linearity of the integral.
3. We can give us a sequence of simple, nonegative functions $s_n$ such that $s_n\rightarrow g$ so, $\int_{x} gd\upsilon=lim \int_{X}s_nd\upsilon=lim\int_{\Omega}s_n \circ fd\mu=\int_{\Omega}g\circ fd\mu$ thanks to MCT, and step 2.

Now we are done with a). **But what really is getting me on my nerves is b).** I know that if g is $\upsilon-integrable$, then $\int_{X} |g|d\upsilon < \infty$ and this imples that $\int_{X} (g)^{+}d\upsilon-\int_{X}(g)^{-}d\upsilon$ but then, im list. Any help would be really appreciated <3

Thanks so much in advance <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$g$ is $\nu$ integrable iff $\int g^{+}d\nu <\infty$ and $\int g^{-}d\nu <\infty$ iff $\int(g\circ f)^{+}d\mu <\infty$ and $\int(g\circ f)^{-}d\mu <\infty$ (by (a)) iff $g\circ f$ is $\mu$ integrable.